# How do I access a priority_queue from another class?

Tags: c++, object, priority-queue

My code looks roughly like this:

```
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

priority_queue <String> pq;

otherClass.qPusher();
pq.pop();

}
```

---

How does qPusher method access priority_queue pq?
I have tried to pass a reference of pq to qPusher, but I can't seem to get the syntax right. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What is `otherClass`? What does `otherClass.qPusher` do?

Comment: Do you mean `qPusher(priority_queue <String>& pq);` in the function declaration? and `otherClass.qPusher(pq);` for the call?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to pass the queue to the class (probably as a constructor argument, likely as a reference, at the very least as a pointer).